# How to Compile Object files into an Archive using Make

Tags: c, makefile

## Problem

I'm writing a B-tree in c and it's getting pretty big. I have a struct for the tree, one for the nodes, and one for the items (key/value). I'd like to compile the object files from all three header files into an archive (.a) using make. Whenever I try to compile using make it uses the archive without every building the objects. Any idea why?

```sh
include/
btree.h
item.h
node.h
```

```sh
src/
btree_attach.c
btree_create.c
btree_destructor.c
btree_disk.c
btree_find.c
btree_get_node.c
btree_insert.c
btree_key_size.c
item_compare_item.c
item_compare_item_qsort.c
item_print_item.c
node_create_.c
node_destructor.c
node_find.c
node_flush_node.c
node_insert.c
node_print_node.c
node_split_node.c
```

```sh
# Generic makefile

# VAriables:
src := $(wildcard *.c)
obj := $(obj:.c=.o)
dep := $(dep:.o=.d)
CFLAGS := -g
INCLUDE =  -Iinclude


all: lib/btree.a\

clean:
    rm -f a.out obj/* bin/*

# ---------------
# Object files

$(obj): $(src) $(dep)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $@ $^


#Archive file
.PHONY: lib/btree.a
lib/btree.a: $(obj) $(dep)
     ar -rv  $@ $^
```

## Update

I changed the make file to the following:

```sh
# VAriables:
src := $(wildcard src/*.c)
obj := $(src:.c=.o)
dep := $(obj:.o=.d)
CFLAGS := -g
INCLUDE = -include 

print:
    $(src)\
    $(obj)\
    $(dep)
     


all: lib/btree.a


# ---------------
# Object files

$(obj): $(src)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $@ $^


#Archive file
lib/btree.a: $(obj) 
     ar -rv  $@ $^
```

The printout has the following

```sh
src/b_util.c src/item_compare_item.c src/b_tree.c src/item_print_item.c src/random_tester_2.c src/node_attach.c src/node_find.c src/node_create_.c src/btree_disk.c src/node_insert.c src/tnode.c src/btree_create.c src/node_unattach.c src/b_tree_test.c src/node_split_node.c src/node_print_node.c src/random_tester_1.c src/node_destructor.c src/btree_insert.c src/item.c src/btree_attach.c src/item_compare_item_qsort.c src/node_flush_node.c src/jdisk.c src/btree_find.c src/btree_destructor.c src/btree_get_node.c src/jdisk_test.c src/btree_key_size.c\
    src/b_util.o src/item_compare_item.o src/b_tree.o src/item_print_item.o src/random_tester_2.o src/node_attach.o src/node_find.o src/node_create_.o src/btree_disk.o src/node_insert.o src/tnode.o src/btree_create.o src/node_unattach.o src/b_tree_test.o src/node_split_node.o src/node_print_node.o src/random_tester_1.o src/node_destructor.o src/btree_insert.o src/item.o src/btree_attach.o src/item_compare_item_qsort.o src/node_flush_node.o src/jdisk.o src/btree_find.o src/btree_destructor.o src/btree_get_node.o src/jdisk_test.o src/btree_key_size.o\
    src/b_util.d src/item_compare_item.d src/b_tree.d src/item_print_item.d src/random_tester_2.d src/node_attach.d src/node_find.d src/node_create_.d src/btree_disk.d src/node_insert.d src/tnode.d src/btree_create.d src/node_unattach.d src/b_tree_test.d src/node_split_node.d src/node_print_node.d src/random_tester_1.d src/node_destructor.d src/btree_insert.d src/item.d src/btree_attach.d src/item_compare_item_qsort.d src/node_flush_node.d src/jdisk.d src/btree_find.d src/btree_destructor.d src/btree_get_node.d src/jdisk_test.d src/btree_key_size.d
```

Essentially they all went to the src dir but I'd like them to be seperated into (see below). Why is it putting everything in src?

```sh
obj/*.o
dep/*.d
src/*.c
```

Comment: `lib/btree.a` isn't a phony target, as you actually create it.

Comment: As for your problem, have you *modified* any of the files used for the static library? And please try to create a [mcve] of your `Makefile`, the one you show contains errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely because your sources variable `src` is empty.  Which means your objects list variable `obj` is empty.  Which means that your library `lib/btree.a` doesn't depend on anything, so make doesn't build anything.

This is most likely because this:

```
src := $(wildcard *.c)
obj := $(obj:.c=.o)
dep := $(dep:.o=.d)
```

should instead be:

```
src := $(wildcard src/*.c)
obj := $(src:.c=.o)
dep := $(obj:.o=.d)
```

It would be more clear if you showed us where your makefile was, and what directory you invoking make from.

You have a lot of other issues as well; for example this:

```
$(obj): $(src) $(dep)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $@ $^
```

is quite wrong.  This says "each object file depends on ALL the source files and ALL the dependency files", and "to build a single object file, you compile ALL the source files".

Comment: Yes, that's wrong too.  But src won't contain anything if the sources are in `src`, as the question implies.  And `dep` is wrong.  Updated the answer.  Thx for the pointer.